# jquery each loop through array with multiple objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, each, nested-loops, javascript-objects

I have a javascript array of multiple objects like the one bellow :

```
var myArray = [{

year:'2015',
model:'BMW',
used:false,
extras: [{buckets:'no',sportWheels:'yes'},{buckets:'no',sportWheels:'yes'}],
color:'blue'

.....

}];
```

What i am trying to do is to loop this array and pass the results into a list, something like this :

```
$.each(myArray, function(i, e){
var year = myArray[i].year;
var model = myArray[i].model;
var used = myArray[i].used;
var color = myArray[i].color;
var extras = myArray[i].extras; 

$('.list').append(year+model+used+color);
});
```

Everything goes well till i want to gather the results of extras. I dont know what to do can anyone suggest something. I thought about a second loop but doesnt work!!!

Comment: A nested loop should work just fine. Please post what you tried and we'll figure out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do each loop for myArray[i].extras

```
    $.each(myArray, function(i, e){
        var year = myArray[i].year;
        var model = myArray[i].model;
        var used = myArray[i].used;
        var color = myArray[i].color;
        var extras = myArray[i].extras; 
        var str=''; 
        $.each(myArray[i].extras, function (index, data) {
            // alert(data.buckets);
            str+='<div>' + year + model + used + color + data.buckets + data.sportWheels +'</div>';
        })
        $('.list').append(str);
        //$('.list').append(year+model+used+color);
    });
```

Comment: Yes i tried this but the problem is that i have more than one model in my array the code i wrote here is a sample and if you append into list like you did here in your example appending more lists than the data that exist , do more looping

Comment: change var str; to var str=''; undefined will be gone. it is my pleasure to help you.

Comment: You're the best buddy , really thank you, you rescued me!!! Have a nice time. bye :) :)

Comment: it is my pleasure to help you.